# No way to replaceState inside react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm setting my props / state from Java by calling a function on `RTCEventEmitter`.
In my component I set the state like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('setState', state => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.setState(state);
        });
    })
}
```

1. I would rather set the properties instead of state, but I don't know how to access the root since there's no `ReactDOM.render` like on the web.
2. I would like to *replace* my state, but `this.replaceState` gives me a deprecation warning. How can I get around this?